# How much must the casino charge for this game for a non-negative expected profit?

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice, geometric-probability, gambling

St. Pete's Casino is introducing a new dice game called "Guess and Win."  After paying (not betting) a fixed ante of $x$ dollars, the player guesses what the next roll of a fair six-sided die will be.

If the player guesses wrong on the first roll, then he/she wins nothing.  Otherwise, the player wins $6^{n+1}$ dollars, where $n$ is the number of consecutive correctly-guessed rolls before an incorrect guess.  For example, a player who guesses correctly and then incorrectly wins $36.

Of course the expected winnings of this game are infinite ... but there's a catch.  A player who guesses correctly on his/her cumulative $20^{th}, 40^{th}, \dots, (20n)^{th}$ roll gets cashed out.  So if you've already rolled 16 times cumulatively, then your maximum winnings for the next round are $6^{4+1} = \$7776$, for a profit of $\$(7776 - x)$.  Or if the next roll will be your cumulative $60^{th}$ roll, you can only win $36 next round.

The casino management want $x$ to be fixed, in particular not depending on the number $N$ of times one has already rolled.  Also, they estimate that the probability that a player will continue to roll given a certain house edge $q$ (which, n.b., does depend on $N$) is given by the following equation:
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\mbox{continue playing}\mid q\Big) = \frac{0.99}{\max\{1, 50q\}}.$$
So there is a 66% probability that a player will roll again if, given his/her cumulative $N$ previous rolls, the house edge in the next round is $3\%$.

1. Find the minimum integer $x$ that results in an expected net profit for the casino long-term (*i.e.*, as the number of players increases without bound), or prove that no such $x$ exists.
2. Assume that no player will roll more than 20 cumulative times.  Find the minimum integer $x$ for which $\mathbb{P}(\mbox{casino profits}\mid\mbox{fixed player}) > 0.6$, or prove that no such $x$ exists.
3. Does the answer to (2) change if the assumed limit on a player's cumulative rolls is dropped?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about how to solve this problem?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Yes, but I'm posing it as a puzzle.  [accidentally pressed Enter, to be continued ...]

Comment: @SuzuHirose
For example, the number $k$ of consecutive correct guesses follows a geometric distribution.  And the expected winnings for a given $N$ (which may be assumed wlog to be $<20$, else divide by 20 and take the remainder) is
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{20-N} \Big(\frac{1}{6}\Big)^k\Big(\frac{5}{6}\Big)\cdot 6^{k+1},$$ which reduces to $$5\cdot \sum_{k = 1}^{20-N} 1 = 5(20 - N) = 100 - 5N.$$

Comment: @SuzuHirose Thus, the expected profit for the casino for a round beginning after the $N^{th}$ cumulative roll is
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\mbox{player will play}\Big)\cdot (x + 5N - 100)$$
$$ = \frac{x + 5N - 100}{\max\{1, 50\Big(1 - \frac{100 - 5N}{x}\Big)\}}$$